# Telephone number dial via computer

Tags: mobile

As part of my “improving workflows and reducing workloads” mentality, I was wondering if anyone had managed to make phone calls from on a hospital computer to patients rather than having to manually dial into you own mobile or office landline. Has anyone made it so you just click on a phone number on the screen and it just calls the patient and you can use the computer speaker and mic (or headset) to talk to the patient? As a dyslexic doctor, I hate manually typing phone numbers, I get them wrong all the time.

If any one has had success with the above, I would love to hear how you did it.

nothing so far. Just seeing what others have done